"The caller does not have permission" when trying to deploy Google Cloud Functions
I'm trying to deploy a cloud function from GitHub Actions using gcloud, this is my command:
gcloud functions deploy delivery-channels \
          --gen2 \
          --runtime=nodejs20 \
          --region=${{ env.GCP_LOCATION }} \
          --source=workspaces/delivery-channels \
          --trigger-http \
          --entry-point=delivery-channel \
          --allow-unauthenticated

This command works on my "development" project, but now that I'm setting up the "production" project it's failing with:
(gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[The caller does not have permission]

The way I'm creating the service account is:
GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT="serviceAccount:github-actions-${DEPLOYMENT_ENV}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
gcloud iam service-accounts create github-actions-${DEPLOYMENT_ENV} --display-name="GitHub Actions (${DEPLOYMENT_ENV})"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/alloydb.client
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member="${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" --role='roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder'
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/cloudfunctions.admin
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/cloudfunctions.developer
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    ${PROJECT_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member "${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
    --role roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/cloudtasks.admin
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/container.admin
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/container.clusterViewer
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/storage.admin

I'm not really sure what I'm missing, the two relevant lines should be:
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT} --role=roles/cloudfunctions.developer
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    ${PROJECT_NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member "${GH_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
    --role roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

I also read cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com service account sometimes requires the serviceAccountUser role as well, so I ran:
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

But I still get the same error.

As stated in the Documentation, To use a runtime service account, the deployer must have the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission on that service account. Can you please try to add the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs and try to redeploy. Also please share the whole error logs. Also make sure to remove any personal and sensitive information

Thanks @SandeepVokkareni, for "runtime" you mean the github actions service account? Shouldn't it error with "Caller is missing permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' on service account" if this permission was missing?

@SandeepVokkareni the error I provided is the only log my command outputs.

I have been debugging this the whole day and it ends out there's a bug with the gcloud CLI. Using a version equal or lower to 482.0.0 will make the deployment succeed.
